# Open form with system info displayed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I would like to be able to open my Form and have this information automatically displayed without having to click a button. How would I go about doing this? This is what I have so far now I am just trying to automate it. I am not a programmer. I am using Visual Basic 2010 Windows Form Application.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByBal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
    Label2.Text = SystemInformation.UserName
    If System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
        Label3.Text = ("64-Bit Operating System")
    Else
        Label3.Text = ("32-Bit Operating System")

    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I fixed the tags for you, so I removed the comment about them.

Comment: Use the forms Load event instead.

Comment: This belongs in the constructor of your form class.  Add `Public Sub New`.  Do avoid telling the user something he already knows, it just isn't useful information.

Comment: Thanks RubberDuck, pinkfloydx33 and Hans Passant for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some have already mentioned, you can do this in the `FormLoadEvent` or the constructor `LoadEvent` of your class...

**Here's for constructor**

```
 Public Sub New()
  ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

  Label1.Text = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
  Label2.Text = SystemInformation.UserName
  If System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
    Label3.Text = ("64-Bit Operating System")
  Else
    Label3.Text = ("32-Bit Operating System")
  End If
End Sub
```

**Your onload event**

```
 Private Sub Me_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  Label1.Text = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
  Label2.Text = SystemInformation.UserName
  If System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
    Label3.Text = ("64-Bit Operating System")
  Else
    Label3.Text = ("32-Bit Operating System")
  End If   

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mr CoDeXer! I used the constructor and it works perfect.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I used the onload event but copied from the constructor. I don't really understand the constructor but I am learning. Thanks again! It looks so much better now.